# Make a program automatically take higher priority?

Tags: java, minecraft, automation, system-monitor

I'm using my Ubuntu OS to play Minecraft. I can get the game to run a little faster by closing my other programs and giving the Minecraft java process a higher priority via the System Monitor. The process is simply named "java" in the list.

[image: I change "Normal" to "Very High"]

How can I make Minecraft automatically take a higher priority when it starts?

Comment: How do you start minecraft?

Comment: Trae7: If the answer below helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** You need `nice` for this:

```
sudo nice -n -20 <your_command>
```

Start minecraft with this command:

```
sudo nice -n -20 su -c java -jar minecraft.jar $USER
```

---

If you have a desktop file for minecraft then change the property `Exec` and install the package `gksu`, we need `gksudo`:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

Example (***Replace*** `<your_username>` with your username, the output of `echo $USER`. `$USER` doesn't works in a desktop file):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Minecraft
GenericName=Game
Comment=Break and place blocks to build imaginative things
Exec=gksudo "nice -n -20 su -c 'java -jar /usr/share/minecraft/minecraft.jar' <your_username>"
Icon=minecraft
Categories=Game
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=net-minecraft-bootstrap-Bootstrap
```

---

> The Linux niceness scale goes from -20 to 19. The lower the number the
>   more priority that task gets. If the niceness value is high number
>   like 19 the task will be set to the lowest priority and the CPU will
>   process it whenever it gets a chance. The default nice value is zero.

<sub>[Source](http://www.nixtutor.com/linux/changing-priority-on-linux-processes/)</sub>

from `man nice`:

```
-n, --adjustment=N
              add integer N to the niceness (default 10)
```